# Exposing SOAP interfaces through a DMZ using Apache httpd

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, soap

I have the following scenario that I am looking for technical guidance.

We want to expose a number of SOAP based services through our company's DMZ using Apache httpd.

To the outside world our clients will have access to 
https://www.mycompany.com/servicea, https://www.mycompany.com/serviceb, etc...

The above services will be redirected via Apache RewriteRules to their true destinations. We will open port 1234 in our firewall to allow SOAP traffic from the DMZ to the internal SOAP listeners.

```
https://www.mycompany.com/servicea --> http://internalip:1234/servicea

https://www.mycompany.com/serviceb --> http://internalip:1234/serviceb
```

Within our intranet I have simulated the above and it works as outlined.

Will the above system description accomplish what we want to do for users outside our intranet? 
Is there a better way or different technologies we should be looking at?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can make these services available externally.
You need to [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) the external IP (ip address of www.mycompany.com) to IP address of Apache HTTPD server over the port 443.

Someone from Network and Security team should be able to help you doing that.

Apache HTTPD need to configure to listen 443 (look for httpd-ssl.conf). 
You may need SSL installation as well.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.mycompany.com
#Any addition code e.g. Rewriterules etc
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /servicea http://internalip:1234/servicea
ProxyPass /serviceb http://internalip:1234/serviceb
<VirtualHost>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Pointed me in the right direction.